# kworkerds process using up all the cpu - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFVnd.png)

I have this weird process using up the all the CPU. I kill it and it gets restarted again.

Not sure what's going on here and how do I proceed further. We have solr, apache and mysql installed on the server.

is this a malware of some type?
[Report on Trend Micro](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/news/cybercrime-and-digital-threats/cryptocurrency-mining-malware-targets-linux-systems-uses-rootkit-for-stealth)

Comment: 1st ddg hit: [cryptominer rootkit](https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-cryptocurrency-miners-are-installing-rootkits-to-hide-themselves/).

Comment: @IporSircer what do you mean?

Comment: Did you find out how to complete get rid of it?

Comment: @iamharish15 no but I found of that it was a malware and was doing crypto mining. Source of the attach was Solr.  We completely got rid of the server and re-setup.

Comment: @Ankit thanks for mentioning Solr is attack vector!